# SQL statement - filtering by latest date

Tags: mysql

I'm learning SQL at school and we have a read only MYSQL database containing information about films.

The films table contains the following columns: distributor_id, film_id, year(year of releas), title.

One question we need to complete is:

" Write a query to find the year of the most recent release from each distributor who has released
more than two films. Your result table should consist of three columns: distributor identifier,
year of release of most recent film and the total number of films released by the distributor."

I'm having trouble with this and what I've managed so far is:

```
SELECT `distributor_id`, COUNT(*) FROM `movieschema`.`films`
GROUP BY `distributor_id`;
```

This gives me a list of the distributor ID's along with the total number of films they have produced.

How can I modify this statement to also return the year of the latest film, where the distributor has produced more than 2 films?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT `distributor_id`, COUNT(*) as TotalFilms, MAX(`year`) LatestFilm
FROM `movieschema`.`films`
GROUP BY `distributor_id`
HAVING TotalFilms > 2
```

Comment: Does MySQL really let you reference TotalFilms in the `HAVING` clause?